# how we can scale the values in wav file if the values are above 1pa in python?

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, wav

Can anyone look about wav file that how we can scale the values in wav file if the values are above 1pa. Normally standard wav file format supports the values 1pa resolution. Maybe python give us some kind of libs for that. 
Thanks,

Comment: For my information, what is a "pa" ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
from scipy.io.wavfile import read
rate, data = read("audio.wav")
print(data.shape) 
#make a copy of the data
new_data = data.copy()
mask = data > 100 # threshold value
new_data[mask] = data[mask] * scale
```